# How can I modify this code so that each table cell can be deleted?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a simple task manager where a user can record "toDos" however, I cannot figure out how to make it so that a user can delete a completed task. Any suggestions?

```
var toDoSpace = document.getElementById("toDospace");

document.getElementById("addToDo").addEventListener('click', function    addToDo()
{
var aToDo = document.getElementById("newToDo").value;

if(document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length == 18)
{
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'To many todos!';  
}
else if (aToDo === '')
{
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Cannot be empty!';
}
else
{    
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
toDoSpace.appendChild(row);
var cell= row.insertCell(0);
cell.innerHTML =  aToDo;      
document.getElementById("newToDo").value = '';
}
});
```

Comment: Just have a new button in each row with an onClick value that deletes the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last *else* block create a delete button and add click event listener. Inside of it you should **removeChild** from your toDoSpace

Here is link to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Answer (score 0):

As Binvention says you'd just need to add an element along with each row that has a click listener with a function for removing the parent row it's contained in. My edit simply involves creating a second cell and using:

```
cellX.innerHTML = "X";

cellX.onclick = function(){ this.parentNode.remove() };
```

to remove the parent row it was put in. Here's the full working example, without styling applied:

```js
var toDoSpace = document.getElementById("toDospace");

document.getElementById("addToDo").addEventListener('click', function    addToDo()
{
var aToDo = document.getElementById("newToDo").value;

if(document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length == 18)
{
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'To many todos!';  
}
else if (aToDo === '')
{
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Cannot be empty!';
}
else
{    
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
toDoSpace.appendChild(row);
var cell= row.insertCell(0);
var cellX= row.insertCell(1);
cell.innerHTML =  aToDo; 
cellX.innerHTML = "X";
cellX.onclick = function(){ this.parentNode.remove() };
document.getElementById("newToDo").value = '';
}
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <div >
    <table id="toDospace">
    </table>
    <input type="text" id="newToDo"></input>
    <button id="addToDo">Add ToDo</button>
  </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```